# can't reference iteration variable in Thymeleaf

Tags: java, spring, thymeleaf

I try to iterate a list of items using `th:each`,

```
<div class="row" th:each="item : *{items}">
  <input type="text" th:field="item.name"/>
</div>
```

it works if I access the iteration variable using `th:text`, but throws

> java.lang.IllegalStateException: Neither BindingResult nor plain
>   target object for bean name 'item' available as request attribute

when I use `th:field` to access it, where did I do wrong?

Comment: Did you try with th:each="item : ${items}" ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this could work:

```
<div class="row" th:each="item, stat : *{items}">
  <input type="text" th:field="*{items[__${stat.index}__].name}"/>
</div>
```

Take a peek here for more info: http://forum.thymeleaf.org/I-have-problem-in-binding-the-list-of-objects-contained-inside-a-object-on-the-form-using-thymeleaf-td3525038.html

Comment: i know this will work, but it's totally weird since you have an iteration variable, but still have to reference the item using index.

Answer (score 0):

th:field is broken in several ways, this is one of them.